# how to make react native and pwa app together

Tags: react-native, react-redux, progressive-web-apps

I have developed one mobile application in react native and its working in android and ios both.

Now I was thinking to make a web application for that. Someone suggested about PWA "Progressive Web Apps". Is possible to make react native app into PWA . Or do I have to start from scratch?

Is native bridging availabe in PWA?  Please suggest me the correct path. Is it possible to make react native and pwa combine?